# Removing the last 2 rows of each factor level in r

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe, where a factor has different amounts of rows. I would like to remove the last 2 rows of each factor level.
`test<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), val=c(3,5,4,6,7,4,1,6,7,8,4,2,0,3,6,8,1,2), trt=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))`

the outcome should look like this:

```
   id val trt
1   1   3   1
2   1   5   1
3   1   4   1
4   2   4   1
5   2   1   1
6   2   6   1
7   2   7   1
8   3   2   2
9   3   0   2
10  3   3   2
11  3   6   2
12  3   8   2
```

An added thing I need is to keep various other columns in the dataframe as well. I edited the example df to include another factor, which is not relevant for this exercise, but I do need it (and a bunch more) for future calculations.

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `filter(test, row_number() < n() - 1, .by = id)`

Comment: That gives me an error and unfortunately I dont know enough about dplyr to fix it.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what error you are running into. Did you run `library(dplyr)` beforehand?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I did. Error in `filter()`:
! We detected a named input.
i This usually means that you've used `=` instead of `==`.
i Did you mean `.by == id`?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>

Comment: Update your package to the latest version (v1.1.4).

Comment: I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it and it still shows version 1.0.8 :/

Comment: Change to `test |> group_by(id) |> filter(row_number() < n() - 1)` but i suspect that you are using an old version of R as well if you are not able to update dplyr.

Comment: Another error: Error: unexpected '>' in "test |>"

Comment: Like I said, you are using an old version of R.

Comment: I dont have administrator rights on this computer, so I cant update it without contacting IT... Any other thoughts on how to solve this? I will contact IT, but I'd love to have a solution before they get back to me in a day or 10.

Comment: Start by using the pipe `%>%`, not base R's `|>`. The latter was introduced in R 4.1. What is your version of R?

Comment: R version 4.0.2 R Studio version 1.3.1058

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE 1/23/2024

A more performant `data.table` option that does not rearrange the original data:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(test)[-test[,.I[(.N - 1L):.N], id][[2]]][]
#>     id val trt
#>  1:  1   3   1
#>  2:  1   5   1
#>  3:  1   4   1
#>  4:  2   4   1
#>  5:  2   1   1
#>  6:  2   6   1
#>  7:  2   7   1
#>  8:  3   2   2
#>  9:  3   0   2
#> 10:  3   3   2
#> 11:  3   6   2
#> 12:  3   8   2
```

Benchmarking against my original answer using a larger dataset:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  SD = test[,.SD[1:(.N - 2)], id],
  I = test[-test[,.I[(.N - 1L):.N], id][[2]]],
  unit = "relative"
)
#> Unit: relative
#>  expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
#>    SD 66.9625 65.77887 56.49757 62.2506 57.49157 17.64804   100
#>     I  1.0000  1.00000  1.00000  1.0000  1.00000  1.00000   100
```

Check that the results are equivalent:

```
identical(
  setorder(test[,.SD[1:(.N - 2)], id], id),
  setorder(test[-test[,.I[(.N - 1L):.N], id][[2]]], id)
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

---

### Original Answer

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(test)[,.(val = val[1:(.N - 2)]), id][]
#>     id val
#>  1:  1   3
#>  2:  1   5
#>  3:  1   4
#>  4:  2   4
#>  5:  2   1
#>  6:  2   6
#>  7:  2   7
#>  8:  3   2
#>  9:  3   0
#> 10:  3   3
#> 11:  3   6
#> 12:  3   8
```

Or, using `.SD` if you have additional columns:

```
setDT(test)[,.SD[1:(.N - 2)], id][]
#>     id val trt
#>  1:  1   3   1
#>  2:  1   5   1
#>  3:  1   4   1
#>  4:  2   4   1
#>  5:  2   1   1
#>  6:  2   6   1
#>  7:  2   7   1
#>  8:  3   2   2
#>  9:  3   0   2
#> 10:  3   3   2
#> 11:  3   6   2
#> 12:  3   8   2
```

Note that this will rearrange the data relative to the original if it is not already grouped by `id`.

Base R (if `test` is sorted by `id`):

```
test[sequence((n <- rle(test$id)[[1]]) - 2, c(1, cumsum(n[-length(n)]) + 1)),]
#>     id val trt
#>  1:  1   3   1
#>  2:  1   5   1
#>  3:  1   4   1
#>  4:  2   4   1
#>  5:  2   1   1
#>  6:  2   6   1
#>  7:  2   7   1
#>  8:  3   2   2
#>  9:  3   0   2
#> 10:  3   3   2
#> 11:  3   6   2
#> 12:  3   8   2
```

Comment: a shorter version might be `setDT(test)[, .(val = first(val, -2)), id]`

Comment: Shorter by a single keystroke for the same whitespace :). However, `first` and `last` have some overhead, so I default to indexing unless it gets too complicated or messy (which is almost never). Try benchmarking the two options with `test <- data.table(id = sample(1e3, 1e6, 1), val = runif(1e6))`.

Comment: haha, true that `first` and `last` have overhead. Straightforward indexing is more efficient, definitely. Forgive me for my code-golfing style

Comment: This is the only option that doesnt give me an error. But I realised it doesnt do entirely what I need on my actual dataframe, as I have a bunch more columns I need to keep, which this doesnt. I edited the original question just now to include that part.

Answer (score 2):

`seq`uences alon *id* by *id* should be shorter than `length` - 1. We can employ `ave` for this and `subset`.

```
> subset(test, ave(id, id, FUN=\(x) seq_along(x) < length(x) - 1L) == 1L)
   id val
1   1   3
2   1   5
3   1   4
6   2   4
7   2   1
8   2   6
9   2   7
12  3   2
13  3   0
14  3   3
15  3   6
16  3   8
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3), val = c(3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 4, 2, 0, 
3, 6, 8, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `n = -2` in `slice_head`

```
> library(dplyr)

> test %>% slice_head(n = -2, by = id)
   id val
1   1   3
2   1   5
3   1   4
4   2   4
5   2   1
6   2   6
7   2   7
8   3   2
9   3   0
10  3   3
11  3   6
12  3   8
```

Comment: Note that this will rearrange the data relative to the original if it is not already grouped by `id`.